# php multidimensional array rename key not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [banner_link] => http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 143038313801.jpg,143038313809.jpg,143038313811.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 143038306301.jpg,143038306302.jpg,143038306303.jpeg,143038306310.jpg,143038306311.jpg,143038306312.png
        )

)
```

Now I want to rename `banner_link` key to `banners`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [banners] => http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 143038313801.jpg,143038313809.jpg,143038313811.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 143038306301.jpg,143038306302.jpg,143038306303.jpeg,143038306310.jpg,143038306311.jpg,143038306312.png
        )

)
```

I have tried with bellow code but no luck.

```
foreach ( $getBefamousHomepage as $k=>$v )
{
    $getBefamousHomepage[$k] ['banners'] = $getBefamousHomepage[$k] ['banner_link'];
    unset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link']);
}
```

Getting this errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: banner_link in /var/www/sitename/application/views/_templates/global_footer.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: banner_link in /var/www/sitename/application/views/_templates/global_footer.php on line 14

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [banners] => http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 
        )

)
```

What I am doing wrong any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Please change your title to a single sentence describing your problem. It's not a Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `banner_link` exists.
And to avoid overwriting `banner` you should check if `banner` not already exists.

```
foreach ( $getBefamousHomepage as $k=>$v ) {    
    if(isset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link']) && !isset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banners'])) {        
        $getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banners'] = $getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link'];
        unset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!. Working perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`banner_link` doesn't always exist. Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to see if it exists
:

```
if(isset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link'])) {
    $getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banners'] = $getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link'];
    unset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost good. You just need to add an extra check to see if banner_link exists.
When it does not, it throws a notice (like you see), but the code will still execute, so the "banner" index will be set to null.

Code example:

```
foreach ( $getBefamousHomepage as $k=>$v )
{
    if (isset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link'])) 
    {
        $getBefamousHomepage[$k] ['banners'] = $getBefamousHomepage[$k] ['banner_link'];
        unset($getBefamousHomepage[$k]['banner_link']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some element of your array don't have banner_link and it is causing the warning when you try to access it. Try this instead:

```
if(isset($getBefamousHomepage[$k] ['banner_link'])) {

    $getBefamousHomepage[$k] = array("banners" => $getBefamousHomepage[$k] ['banner_link']);

}
```